# Vertically rotate visual block

Tags: visual-mode, visual-block, rearrangement

How would one vertically rotate a visual block of text?

For example given this:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Select those characters in visual block and rotate them once:

```
o
h
e
l
l
```

As you see, every character is moved down one line, and the last character (`o`) is wrapped around and put on top

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

- select the lines you want to rotate (with `V` or `<C-v>`)
- type `:`
- type `<C-w>` to get rid of the `'<,'>` that appeared after the `:`
- type `'> move '<-1`, or the short version `'>m'<-`
- press `<Enter>`

**Explanation**

The `move` command accepts a range to move and an address to where the content should be moved (see `:help move`).

In this case `'>` is the range. It translates to "the last line of the visual selection". On the other hand, `'<-` is the address where we want the selected range to be moved to. It means "the line before (`-`) the first visually selected line (`'<`)".

This can be difficult to type and you have to get rid of the `'<,'>` that appears when you type `:` in Visual mode.

### Solution 2

It is much easier to just select all the lines but the last and type `dp`. This will delete the selected lines (`hell`) and put them after the `o`.

Comment: Solution 2 only works in Visual Line mode, though.

Comment: This does not work as expected (no, not even solution 1).  I believe you missed that this is to be executed on a visual block, *not* in visual line mode.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that works even if there are surrounding characters:

```
kdjP`]lx`<P
```

Which can be mapped to a key like so:

```
vnoremap <C-r> kdjP`]lx`<P
```

---

Explanation (here, bolded letters symbolize the cursor / selected text):

Initial text:

```
.......
...h...
...e...
...l...
...l...
...o...
.......
```

`kdjP`: cut all but the last letter and paste it one row down:

```
.......
......
...h...
...e...
...l...
...lo...
.......
```

`` `]lx ``: go to the end of the text that was just pasted (`` `] ``), move to the character next to it (`l`), and cut it (`x`)<sup>1</sup>:

```
.......
......
...h...
...e...
...l...
...l...
.......
```

`` `<P ``: go back to the beginning of the original visual selection (`` `< ``), and paste the last character you just deleted (`P`):

```
.......
...o...
...h...
...e...
...l...
...l...
.......
```

---

<sup>1: the dot to the right of the `l` is bolded, although it's hard to see.</sup>